# ModelSim Error : " could not find interpreter "ScintillaTk" "

Tags: modelsim

I have installed ModelSim 10.4 X64, when I want to open a vhd file in editor an error shown in "Transcript" window as :
" could not find interpreter "ScintillaTk" "

I searched about that and I found out that this problem occurs when ModelSim installation path have a space character !!

I have installed it in "Program Files" Folder, Now how can I solve this problem without installing it again ?

I have changed the "Path" environment variable`s value form -path- to -"path"- but the problem not solved ...

Comment: Create a directory junction from somewhere like ```C:\modelsim\``` to ```C:\Program Files\<modelsim folder>\``` and set the path, environment variables, and shortcuts for modelsim to point to that location?

Comment: Thank you @TomCarpenter, I think that is better to be as an answer with more explain and images, If you don't time for that, I'm glad to do that.

Comment: What do you mean "directory junction"

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Tom Carpenter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/53368/tom-carpenter) for his solution I write the answer for others who may have the same problem.

> Create a directory junction from somewhere like C:\modelsim\ to C:\Program Files\ (modelsim folder)\ and set the path, environment variables, and shortcuts for modelsim to point to that location? – [Tom Carpenter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/53368/tom-carpenter) Feb 27 '16 at 19:35

this can be solved by creating directory junction link to modelsim installation folder. 
you can create link with `mklink` command in cmd.
`mklink /J "Link" "Destination"`
e.g. `mklink /J "C:\modelsim" "D:\program file\modelsim"`
after creating the link the path in environment variables should be updated with the link address.
The shourcut target should get updated too.
e.g. `C:\modelsim\win32pe_edu\modelsim.ex`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same bug. It's more simple than doing that with mklink.

Just move the installation folder in C:\ -> that will be enough. Good luck guys!